# Mantis - Integrate Wiki

Tags: php, mysql, wiki, mantis

I am using [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org) (PHP and MysQL) as a bug tracking tool and I would like to extend it in order to document requirements and technical specifications. Ideally, I should be able to link a defect with a requirement.

Is there a way to integrate a [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki) tool (preferably PHP and MySQL based) into Mantis?

EDITED:

- Instructions how to integrate
  [DocuWiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org) can be found in this
  article "[Integrating DokuWiki
  with Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt:issue:7075:integration_with_dokuwiki)"
- Instructions how to integrate
  [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/) can be found [here](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=8054)
  (Thanks Ian)
- Instructions how to integrate
  [TWiki](http://twiki.org/) can be found [here](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt:issue:8757) and
  [here](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=8757)

Suggested alternatives to Mantis: (open source bugtrackers with integrated Wiki)

1. [TikiWiki](http://info.tikiwiki.org/tiki-index.php) (Php)
2. [PhpWiki](http://phpwiki.sourceforge.net/) (Php)
3. [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) (Python) (Thanks ax)
4. [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) (Ruby on Rails) (Thanks Paul)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Mantis can be integrated with DocuWiki](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt:issue:7075:integration_with_dokuwiki)

Answer (score 6):

**DokuWiki** will be a good choice.

Read this: [Integrating DokuWiki with Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt:issue:7075:integration_with_dokuwiki)

Comment: I cannot see the content on this page - it looks like I need an account with mantisbt.org website

Comment: Adrian: Login as Anonymous. Trick: use this link first then copy-paste the other.

Comment: I was able to access the document "Integrating DokuWiki with Mantis" in PDF format http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/file_download.php?file_id=1032&type=bug

It is a good starting point but the information appears old (last update May 2007). Do you know anything more up to date? I am also a bit concerned about changing the Mantis code but I am willing to try.

Comment: Oddly enough, the accepted link above now points to the same page and no login is required.

Answer (score 2):

instead of trying to integrate 2 different, uncoordinated software packages, i would suggest to use an issue tracker with integrated wiki (and VCS interface, reporting, timeline, roadmap, etc.): [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). you can import your Mantis bugs into Trac with [mantis2trac](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/MantisImportScript).

Comment: no, the 'do one thing' mantra works well for OSS projects, as a result they have to provide good interoperability hooks, so tying them together means you can have the best of both worlds. This is a strong feature of much OSS software. Not to say that Trac isn't good mind.

Comment: I am trying to tie `dokuwiki` into a bug tracker with SVN support, so far `trac` isn't it because I don't have access to the server on which the SVN repo is.

Answer (score 2):

The mediawiki instructions also work for Mindtouch.