# How to integrate a wiki with Mantis bug tracker

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, bug-tracking, mantis, dokuwiki

I have read the [original](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mantisbt%3aissue:8253) and [updated](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt%3aissue:7075%3aintegration_with_dokuwiki) guides in the Mantis Wiki on how to integrate DokuWiki, but when I follow those instructions now it gives me a number of errors. While doing so I noticed that a lot of Wiki integration is now already supported, and the instructions conflict with what is already there.

In the administrator and developer guides in the Mantis documentation there is nothing relating to wiki integration, and I don't see anything in plugins either.

So, where will I find decent documentation on integrating a Wiki (the DokuWiki on has some excellent integration, would prefer that) with Mantis?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mantis - Integrate Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554041/mantis-integrate-wiki)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the answer was on the original page, but fairly easy to miss. Basically just ignore everything in the Mantis Steps section, and edit the wiki values in the `config_inc.php` file.